# Is "new" keyword mandatory in javascript?

Tags: javascript, keyword

I heard somewhere that new keyword is not mandatory everywhere. Is that true?

```
app.post('/tasks', (req, res) => {
    const task = new Task(req.body)
```

here if i dnt write new, its still working.
I am confuse about this keyword

```
validate(value) {
            if(value.toLowerCase().includes('password')) {
                throw new Error(`Password can't be "password"`)
            }
        }
```

```
const add = (a, b) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(a + b)
        }, 2000)
    })
}
```

Again here if i dnt give new ,its not working.
Can someone elaborate the difference?

Comment: you can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

Comment: nice duplicate :-(

Comment: It's only possible to omit `new` if the function supports it. You can create such a function yourself as well: https://jsfiddle.net/50w6Lvru/

Comment: Usually you use `new` when you're calling a constructor function or a class in order to create an instance of the constructor/class. Some (especially) host objects can be called without `new` operator, when they might return a different result, ex. `Date]()` returns a string when called without `new`. Some libraries have contructors, which detect they were called by `new`, and if it wasn't used, they call themselves with `new` operator, forcing a new instance to be created.

Comment: Things like this can get a bit confusing.  The reason is that a function might be a plain vanilla function that maintains state using closures, a constructor function, and even a factory pattern.  One hint that it's a class might be to look at is prototype.

Answer (score 2):

The `new` keyword [has a number of effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) when you use it.

Typically, a regular function is designed to be used without it.

Typically, a constructor function is designed to be used *only* with it.

**Sometimes**, a function may be designed in such a way that it can work with and without it.

For example:

```js
function Duck() {
    if (this instanceof Duck) {
        return this;
    }
    return new Duck();
}

const swedish_blue = Duck();
const welsh_harlequin = new Duck();

console.log(swedish_blue instanceof Duck);
console.log(welsh_harlequin instanceof Duck);
```

If it is designed to work with or without `new` then it might, as in the example above, simply apply `new` itself. It could also have different behaviour.

```js
const date_string = Date();
const date_obj = new Date();
console.log(typeof date_string, date_string instanceof Date);
console.log(typeof date_obj, date_obj instanceof Date);
```